# MouseEnter, MouseLeave, etc, Event Handlers on a second PictureBox Fail to Fire

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, picturebox, visual-studio-2022, wisej

I have a large WiseJ vb.net program which has multiple Picturebox controls.  An image is loaded into the control on one event, the cursor changes on another etc.  Each picturebox use four different events for my functionality.  The first picturebox executes the events flawlessly.  On the second identically specified picturebox the event handler fails to fire.  It won't even execute the breakpoint.  I have 8 such picture boxes but only one fires the event handler.  I've searched for solutions and tried some but none really address my problem.

I had initially simply copied the working first picturebox code, pasted them, and edited the names to match the next picturebox.  This has normally worked well to save time.  I then deleted the second picturebox code and went to the page. I double-clicked the offending picture box which generated the click event. The new event still did not fire.  I considered a solution which removed the event handler in each picturebox, but frankly, I've added events on pictureboxes so many times and they work fine.  I'm guessing something is corrupted behind the scenes but in reviewing the project pages I see no reference to the pictureboxes and am not sure where to look.  It's odd that one works fine with all the events but a second fails.

This even works

```
Private Sub PicFrontLR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PicFrontLR.Click
        If SpkrDragged = False Then
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            LoadSpkrinView(0, "System")
        End If
End Sub
```

This event fails

```
Private Sub PicFrontC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PicFrontC.Click
        If SpkrDragged = False Then
            Cursor = Cursors.Default
            LoadSpkrinView(1, "System")
        End If
End Sub
```

I'm hoping I'm missing something, because one of the solutions involved recreating the page and systematically looking for a failure as I went.  This page has a lot of code.  Almost done with it and everything else seems to work perfectly.

Comment: How exactly did you add the subsequent picture boxes?  Was that via copy/paste too?  If so, what happens if you drag a new picture box onto your form from the toolbox?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I needed to draw new PictureBoxes vs. copy and pasting them?  I drew the first and did copy and paste the others.  I'll try drawing one from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: I tried deleting the offending picture box and drawing a fresh one adding the events.  No difference.

Comment: My picture boxes are each enclosed in a separate group box, it's handy for labeling.  I switched the events control from the picture box to the enclosing group box.  The events started working.  The only issue is that the click event doesn't fire if I'm over the picture box; a major problem.  I believe it's significant that the events work, but just not over the picture box.   Need to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured this one out, mostly.  It turns out that a picturebox "apparently" only triggers certain events if there's an image in it.  Maybe basic knowledge but I hadn't run into this before.  I simply added both a load picture event for the picture box and one for the container.  If there's no image the container event fires.  If there's an existing picture the picturebox event fires.

One unexplained issue is that the first picture box in a group of eight copied picture boxes, still fires the picturebox event even if there's no picture.  As stated the picture box properties are all identical as are the containers.  This is what confused me as one event worked and the others did not.  Maybe someone can explain.